# Network link on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, google-api-client, kmz

I have created a Google map in an HTML page with a KMZ overlay and it displays properly. I have then tried to use a network link to display the KML file in order to have it refresh periodically, since the data in the KML file content can change. This however does not work.

The part of the HTML code for the Google Map and KML (that works) looks as follows (I have just entered a fake url).

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
    var windhoek = {lat: -22.8, lng: 17.6};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4.5,
        center: windhoek
    });
    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'http://www.example.com/kml_file_ovelay.kmz',
      map: map
    });
}
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

I have then created a network link file (network_link_file.kmz) that references this kml_file_ovelay.kmz file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
    <NetworkLink>
    <Link>
        <href>http://www.example.com.na/kml_file_ovelay.kmz</href>
        <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
        <refreshInterval>30</refreshInterval>
    </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

I have opened this file with Google Earth and it works as expected.

The HTML file was changed to reference the network link file as follows.

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
    var windhoek = {lat: -22.8, lng: 17.6};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4.5,
    center: windhoek
    });
    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'http://www.example.com/network_link_file.kmz',
      map: map
    });
    }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Now, the Google Map still appears, but the KMZ overlay never appears. I have tried different browsers to see if it may be a caching problem. It states in the Google Maps APIs documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) that network links are supported for Google Maps to import data dynamically, so I must be doing something wrong, I assume in my network_link_file.kmz file.

Does anyone know what may be causing this? My searches on this issue did not reveal anything useful as to what may be the problem in this case.

Any help would be appreciated.

---Answer provided by BarryHunter ---

I have posted the same question on https://support.google.com. A post from BarryHunter provided the answer (thanks Barry!). Javascript can also be used to force the refresh as follows.

```
var ctaLayer = false;
function refreshLayer() {
if (ctaLayer)
    ctaLayer.setMap(null);
    ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/kml_file_overlay.kmz?r=' + (new Date()).getTime(),
        map: map
    });
}
setInterval(refreshLayer, 10000);
```

With this approach, a Network Link file is not even required. Hope this helps others!

Comment: I remember this problem from a while ago, If I remember it was cache, and I resolved this by appending `?r=41241` to the `http://www.example.com/network_link_file.kmz` path like `http://www.example.com/network_link_file.kmz?r=41241` using a random number for each call.

Comment: Also zoom completely out and check your layer is not being applied in the wrong place, that happened too.

Comment: Thank you for the help so far, @pokeybit. Adding the r=41241 made the kmz file to display on the map (which is a good step in the right direction!). I have then overwritten the kmz file with a new one that displays different map data, but on the same map location, but even if I change r=41241 to a different value, the old kmz file is still loaded on the map (?). I have also cleared my browser's cache, but still the old kmz file is displayed.... . Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: You probably need to refresh the browser as well - try F5 and see if that works.

Comment: I have posted the same question on https://support.google.com. A post from BarryHunter provided the answer (thanks Barry!). Javascript can also be used to force the refresh as follows.

var ctaLayer = false;
function refreshLayer() {
if (ctaLayer)
 ctaLayer.setMap(null);
 ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: 'http://www.example.com/kml_file_overlay.kmz?r=' + (new Date()).getTime(),
  map: map
 });
}
setInterval(refreshLayer, 10000);

With this approach, a Network Link file is not even required. Hope this helps others!

Comment: Sorry about the code not displaying properly in my comment above. I have added Barry's answer to my original post for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working as expected

```
ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/kml_file_overlay.kmz?r=' + (new Date()).getTime(),
        map: map
    });
```

it's enough in JS, without any other code, to get the kmz or kml file updated in google maps